# Add a new key in the mongodb collection document using aggrigate

Tags: mongodb

I want to add a new field into the collection document after match. Yes, I can do this but I need to execute 4 more query at a time for different users. So, please find me a solution that how to insert a new key using aggrigation

```js
 /* Prepare Request */
  const match = {
    $match: {$and: [{_id: ObjectId(id)}, {active: true}, {referredBy: null}]}
  };

  const pipline = [match];

  /* Process Request */
  CamperModal.aggregate(pipline).exec((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return ResUtil.error(response, error, 'Error to update');
    }

    ResUtil.success(response, data);
  });
};
```

After match operation I need to add new field into the mongodb document

Comment: Can you please add sample collection json and output you need after aggregate and from where additional key will come?

Comment: before aggrigation json is 
{
  name: "abc",
  active: true,
  _id: "",
  ...
}

After Query
{
  name: "abc",
  active: true,
  referredBy: ObjectId()
  _id: "",
  ...
}

Comment: Do you need to add referredBy in resposne,if yes from where it's value will come from?

Comment: I need to update a new field in the document after match which should save into the collection ie in the above example : referredBy key should update into the collection of match document

Comment: after the aggregate runs, if you want to save a new key in collection then you have to run an update query on that matched document and in update add the referredBy key

Comment: please can you give one example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199100/discussion-between-rakesh-kumar-sharma-and-sushant-mehta).